# How to fix renaming methods ? "The systems cannot find the file specified"

Tags: batch-rename

I've tried to rename file from someFile_v4 to someFile_v5 in all folders. Unfortunately  I've get error The system cannot find the file specified.

```
@echo off
for /R %%f in (*_v4.xml) do call :ProcessFile 
goto :Finished
:ProcessFile
rename "*_v4.xml" "*_v5.xml"
goto :eof
:Finished
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using a `for` loop, which actually does nothing with the variable in this.

Try the following:

## (

I also suggest you to consider changing:

> `for /r` to `for /f` in using `dir /s /b /a-d` in the loop.

## )

```bat
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d "*_v4.xml"') do (

    set "_ren=%%~fi"
    for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /w /b "%%~i"') do set "_to=%%~nxI"
    ren "!_ren!" "!_to:_v4=_v5!"
    set _ren=0<nul & set _to=0<nul

)
```

I cannot explain my code, sorry, because I don't know English well.